# Not Riemann integrable derivative

Tags: integration, derivatives

Is there a function $F:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ differentiable with $F' = f$, but $f$ is not Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$. $[a,b]$ is a bounded interval?

**Motivation**
Rudin page 152 Theorem 7.17: Suppose $\{f_n\}$ a sequence of functions, differentiable on $[a,b]$ and such that $\{f_n(x_0)\}$ converges for some point $x_0\in [a,b]$. If $\{f_n'\}$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$ to $g$, then $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$ to $f$ where $f' = g$.

In the remark, it says if the continuity of the function $f'_n$ is assumed in addition to the above hypothesis, then a much shorter proof can be based on fundamental theorem of calculus and the theorem that $\int_a^b f_n d\alpha\to\int_a^b f d\alpha$ if we have  $f_n\to f$ uniformly.

I was thinking that we don't really need $f_n'$ to be continuous, we just need it to be Riemann integrable so we can apply Fundamental Thm of Calculus. From the remark I guess that there should be a derivative that is not integrable.
_
**EDIT**
[Dominic Michaelis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348265/not-riemman-integrable-derivaitive/348267?noredirect=1#348267) answered my question immediately. A further thought yields a more difficult question, is there a function as said above with $f'$ bounded on $[a,b]$?

Comment: There is a **great** example of this and other shortcomings of the Riemann integral in Abbott's excellent book *Understanding Analysis*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $F[-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ with
$$F(x)= \begin{cases}
x^2 \sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right) & x \neq 0\\
0 & x=0 \\ 
\end{cases}
$$
The derivative is not a regulated function, and not bounded at $0$. I don't know a definition of riemann integrable allowing those things.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you perhaps look at the EDIT as well?

Comment: @mezhang when you say F' is bounded, it is a more difficult situation. Whats the exact definition of Riemann integrable in your course? I know 2 standard definitions, for one I have a counter example, for another I don't know if there is one

Comment: If $\inf_{P} \sum_{i = 1}^n M_i x_i = \sup_{P} \sum_{i = 1}^n m_i x_i $ for example as in Rudin.